# Textbox Wrong Value

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I have an asp.net page with a datalist with few textboxes, and a submit button.
when i cahnge the text in the textbox, and click submit, the value i get in the vb code is the old value and not the one i just entered.

Any idea?

thanks

Comment: You mind showing us the code?

Comment: Are you sure you're not binding your TextBox on every postback?

Comment: Are you binding the data list everytime the page posts back? Try using the !Page.IsPostback flag to bind the list.

Comment: Can you provide your datalist markup code?

Comment: YES. i do bind on every page load...You think this is the problem???
It won't let me post the code here, because it's too long.

Comment: Prefect!!! Ispostback = false.
Thank you very much guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two possible reasons for this.

Either (1) the part of your code that sets this value is being run at postback, thus resetting it, or (2) your textbox is disabled in .NET code (and enabled in javascript) so that .NET assumes that its value cannot have changed, and doesn't check the POST data.

Sorry for C# code examples, but i'm sure you'll work it out:

## 1:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack) { myTextBox.Value = "original value"; }
```

## 2:

```
string valueFromTextbox = Request.Form[myTextBox.ClientID];
```